# How to get parameter values for dm_exec_sql_text

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I'm running the following statement to see what queries are executing in sql server:

```
select *
from sys.dm_exec_requests r
cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle)
where r.database_id = DB_ID('<dbname>')
```

The sql text that comes back is parameterized:

```
(@Parm0 int) select * from foo where foo_id = @Parm0
```

Is there any way to get the values for the parameters that the statement is using?  Say by joining to another table perhaps?

Comment: A little more work to get it out that way, but it works if I have to have it.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever discover a solution to this? The accepted answer doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit : Remus is correct, this will only bring out the compiled versions on the first time that the query plan hit the cache, not subsequent runs.

You should be able to get the parameters from the query plan, since it contains the last parameters used. Altering your code:

```
select * 
from sys.dm_exec_requests r 
cross apply sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle) as qp
cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) 
where r.database_id = DB_ID('<dbname>')
```

You will find the final column of the query plan is query_plan, an xml version of the query plan which you can manually inspect, at the bottom of the XML are the parameters, or if you fancy the challenge use XML parsing and XQuery to pull out the ParameterList tags

Comment: I think those are the parameters sniffed during plan generation, not the last ones used.

Comment: Your right, that make's this a mare since I see no other DMV that gives a record of what the simple / forced parameterisation has done to the statement

Comment: WRT "if you fancy the challenge use XML Parsing...", see [blog post](http://www.intheclouds.blog/2018/12/31/extracting-executable-statements-from-sql-server-query-plans/).

Answer (score 4):

In case someone stumble upon this thread looking for a proper solution (which the other answers sadly lack), I found this [helpful post from mssqltips](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4992/how-to-find-compiled-parameter-values-for-sql-server-cached-plans/).

I cleaned-up and tweaked the query a little bit to make this one:

```sql
-- cleanup
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#compiledValue') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #compiledValue
GO

-- Prepare temp table #compiledValue
SELECT  
    OBJECT_NAME(est.objectid) ObjectName,
    DB_NAME(est.dbid) DBName,
    eqs.last_execution_time,
    est.text,
    (eqs.statement_start_offset / 2) + 1 AS statement_start_offset,
    (IIF(eqs.statement_end_offset = -1, DATALENGTH(est.text), eqs.statement_end_offset) - eqs.statement_start_offset) / 2 + 1 AS statement_end_offset,
    TRY_CONVERT(XML, 
        SUBSTRING(etqp.query_plan,
            CHARINDEX('<ParameterList>',etqp.query_plan),
            CHARINDEX('</ParameterList>',etqp.query_plan) + LEN('</ParameterList>') - CHARINDEX('<ParameterList>',etqp.query_plan) )) AS statement_params
INTO #compiledValue
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats eqs
     CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(eqs.sql_handle) est
     CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_text_query_plan(eqs.plan_handle, eqs.statement_start_offset, eqs.statement_end_offset) etqp

SELECT 
    cvalue.last_execution_time,
    cvalue.DBName,
    cvalue.ObjectName,
    SUBSTRING(cvalue.text,cvalue.statement_start_offset,cvalue.statement_end_offset) AS sql_text,
    pc.compiled.value('@Column', 'nvarchar(128)') AS Parameterlist,
    pc.compiled.value('@ParameterCompiledValue', 'nvarchar(128)') AS [compiled Value]
FROM #compiledValue cvalue
OUTER APPLY cvalue.statement_params.nodes('//ParameterList/ColumnReference') AS pc(compiled)
WHERE cvalue.text NOT LIKE '%#compiledValue%' -- ignore these queries based on temp table name
ORDER BY cvalue.last_execution_time DESC
GO

-- cleanup
DROP TABLE #compiledValue
GO
```

It works quite well, and each parameters will have its own line.

For instance:
[image: Screen capture from MS SQL Server Management Studio of the result]

Comment: This shows compiled parameter values, not the ones which the query is running with now.

Answer (score 2):

A query that give the login name, hour of execution and query as text of last events, if you can give a hand to the join of sys.dm_exec_query_stats, but it works

```
SELECT distinct
s.login_name,
qs.creation_time 
,SUBSTRING(st.text, (qs.statement_start_offset/2) + 1,
((CASE statement_end_offset
  WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(st.text)
  ELSE qs.statement_end_offset END
  - qs.statement_start_offset)/2) + 1) AS statement_text
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions S
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections AS c ON S.session_id = c.session_id
,sys.dm_exec_query_stats QS --qs on c.most_recent_sql_handle = qs.sql_handle
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) AS st
WHERE ST.text LIKE '%yourKeyWord%' and s.login_name <> 'NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT'
order by qs.creation_time desc
```

Comment: Don't know why this answer hasn't been shown more love, it comes a lot closer than the selected answer in my opinion - you can more easily find the actually executed queries.

Comment: Hi @Marco, I've never seen this kind of syntax before 
`LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections AS c ON S.session_id = c.session_id
,sys.dm_exec_query_stats QS --qs on c.most_recent_sql_handle = qs.sql_handle`
Is the sys.dm_exec_query_stats table being left joined to sys.dm_exec_connections?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a version prior to SQL Server 2012 or Amazon RDS where the TRY_CONVERT function does not exist, this is a variation of the Indigo query that will work.

```
-- cleanup
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#compiledValue') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #compiledValue
GO

-- Prepare temp table #compiledValue
SELECT  
    OBJECT_NAME(est.objectid) ObjectName,
    DB_NAME(est.dbid) DBName,
    eqs.last_execution_time,
    est.text,
    (eqs.statement_start_offset / 2) + 1 AS statement_start_offset,
    (IIF(eqs.statement_end_offset = -1, DATALENGTH(est.text), eqs.statement_end_offset) - eqs.statement_start_offset) / 2 + 1 AS statement_end_offset,
    --TRY_CONVERT(XML, 
    --    SUBSTRING(etqp.query_plan,
    --        CHARINDEX('<ParameterList>',etqp.query_plan),
    --        CHARINDEX('</ParameterList>',etqp.query_plan) + LEN('</ParameterList>') - CHARINDEX('<ParameterList>',etqp.query_plan) )) AS statement_params,
    CASE
        WHEN CHARINDEX('<ParameterList>', etqp.query_plan) > 0
            THEN CONVERT(XML, 
                    SUBSTRING(etqp.query_plan, 
                        CHARINDEX('<ParameterList>', etqp.query_plan), 
                        CHARINDEX('</ParameterList>', etqp.query_plan) + LEN('</ParameterList>') - CHARINDEX('<ParameterList>', etqp.query_plan) )) 
        ELSE NULL
    END AS statement_params
INTO #compiledValue
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats eqs
     CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(eqs.sql_handle) est
     CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_text_query_plan(eqs.plan_handle, eqs.statement_start_offset, eqs.statement_end_offset) etqp

SELECT 
    cvalue.last_execution_time,
    cvalue.DBName,
    cvalue.ObjectName,
    SUBSTRING(cvalue.text,cvalue.statement_start_offset,cvalue.statement_end_offset) AS sql_text,
    pc.compiled.value('@Column', 'nvarchar(128)') AS Parameterlist,
    pc.compiled.value('@ParameterCompiledValue', 'nvarchar(128)') AS [compiled Value]
FROM #compiledValue cvalue
OUTER APPLY cvalue.statement_params.nodes('//ParameterList/ColumnReference') AS pc(compiled)
WHERE cvalue.text NOT LIKE '%#compiledValue%' -- ignore these queries based on temp table name
ORDER BY cvalue.last_execution_time DESC
GO

-- cleanup
DROP TABLE #compiledValue
GO
```