# Microsoft SQL Server database locks

Tags: sql-server-2012

A lot of times database locks appear on our Microsoft SQL Server database. The blocker query appears as Fetch
API_CURSOR000000000004D888. This string is just a sample. But it is always an API_CURSOR0000000XXXXX some value. We were able to find the SQL query running behind this cursor using steps in articles like

https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/joe/hunting-down-the-origins-of-fetch-api_cursor-and-sp_cursorfetch/

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f51618eb-5332-4f10-9985-b343933579da/fetch-apicursor-unusual?forum=sqldatabaseengine

We could find the SQL query that is blocking the database. It looked like this below. Every time it is the same query.

```
session_id properties creation_time is_open text 200 API | Dynamic | Scroll Locks | Global (0) 05:44.8 1 (@P1 nchar(10))

SELECT * 
FROM JDE_PRODUCTION.PRODDTA.F00022 (UPDLOCK) 
WHERE (UKOBNM = @P1) 
FOR UPDATE OF UKOBNM, UKUKID
```

I am seeking help here to see if there is a way we can find the actual values that are passed in the variable @P1. Please let me know if someone has ideas or already done this.

Comment: If you want to catch the values you need a trace or an XEvent session. Declare it as a `FAST_FORWARD` cursor might speed it up?

Comment: did you check this seems similar : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509263/how-to-get-parameter-values-for-dm-exec-sql-text

Answer (score -1):

no you will not be. rather check with your application team and see how the DB connections are set up.

if its a Docker Image/Container then check the Database URL, there they may have set SelectMethod = Cursor.

with such settings, every query passed via this Connection will make Cursor call to SQL Server which is unnecessary.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).